# get gridview datakeys values in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to get gridview datakeys value in JavaScript.

I know that we can get gridview cell value using

```
 col1 = grid.rows[i].cells[5];
```

But I use Autogeneratedcolumn = "true"

so it bind with different number of column each time and there is no specific place where my datakey bind for ex-

**for 1 scenario gridview can bind like**

```
Code  A1 A2 A3 Tot
as1    1  2  3  6
as2    2  3  4  9
```

**for 2nd scenario gridview can bind like**

```
Code  A1 A2  Tot
as1    1  2   3
as2    2  3   5
```

**Tot** is my datakey I want to get this value in JavaScript function

Comment: Can't you just check the length of grid.rows[i] and then return tot1=grid.rows[i].cells[grid.rows[i].length-1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Tot column will always be Tot, and no other column would have that name, you could search for the header datakey text and retrieve the row values based on it:

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=grd.ClientID %>');
var header = grid.rows[0];
var dataKeyIndex = -1;
var dataKeyHeaderText = "Tot";

//Find index of the DataKey column
for (var i = 0; i < header.cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = header.cells[i];
    if (cell.innerText == dataKeyHeaderText) {
        dataKeyIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if(dataKeyIndex != -1){

    //Loop the rows retrieving the value
    for (var i = 0; i < header.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = header.rows[i];
        var dataKeyValue = row.cells[dataKeyIndex];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your Tot column always the last column?

```
var cells = grid.rows[i].cells
col1 = cells[cells.length-1];
```